# Telerik RadGrid Filtertemplate as RadCombobox UI is not proper

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using Telerik RadGrid control in which I added FilterTemplate as RadComboBox for providing filter to particular column but that RadComboBox is not looking proper.

PFA for screenshot of RadComboBox.
[image]

Code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridApplications" Skin="Metro" SkinID="Metro" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnNeedDataSource="RadGridApplications_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" 
ShowStatusBar="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" runat="server">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ProductID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Application ID" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" AllowFiltering="false">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Application Name" HeaderStyle-Width="65%" AllowFiltering="false">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" FilterControlAltText="Status" ReadOnly="true">
                <FilterTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Status_filter" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="100%" 
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="selectedindexchanged" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.GetColumn("Status").CurrentFilterValue %>'>
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Active" Value="Active"/>
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="In-Active" Value="In-Active" ViewStateMode="enabled" />
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>

                    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="radscriptblock1" runat="server">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function selectedindexchanged(sender, args) {
                                var tableview = $find("<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.ClientID %>");
                            tableview.filter("status", args.get_item().get_value(), "equalto");
                            }  
                        </script>
                    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>

                </FilterTemplate>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn Text="Edit" ItemStyle-CssClass="editlink" DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductID" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AddEditApplication.aspx?Mode=Edit&ID={0}" AllowFiltering="false">
            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: What version of Telerik are you using?  What browsers does it not look correct in?  Are there any browsers where it does look correct?

Comment: In all browser it shows same UI and i am using 2013.2.717.40 Version for Telerik dll.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some CSS overrides the RadComboBox default settings. Examine the rendered HTML in the browser dev toolbar and find the rules that break it so you can override them if needed.

OR, remove all your custom CSS from the page and if the problem is gone - start adding it piece by piece.

This works fine for me with your code (I only added a dummy datasource, removed the additional columns and rand the page):[image]

and

[image]

Comment: yes its correct because if i do same code on empty page then it works fine. but i tried by removing all css still result is same for that page. It means CSS is not an issue. i am not getting what is actual issue.

Comment: Obviously, something on that page breaks the combo's CSS. Compare a blank page with yours and see what the difference is so you can fix it.